# How to specify openstack_blockstorage_volume_attach_v2.host_name?

Tags: terraform

I've defined an instance with no custom volume attachments. This was created successfully by someone else. Now I'm trying to add another instance which is identical except for

- the resource ID,
- the `openstack_compute_instance_v2.name` and
- it has an attached volume.

The relevant bits of the .tf file:

```
resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "foo_1" {
  name            = "foo_1"
  image_name      = "…"
  flavor_name     = "…"
  key_pair        = "${var.key_pair}"
  security_groups = […]
}

resource "openstack_blockstorage_volume_v2" "foo_volume_1" {
  name = "foo_volume_1"
  size = 100
}

resource "openstack_blockstorage_volume_attach_v2" "foo_volume_1_attachment" {
  volume_id = "${openstack_blockstorage_volume_v2.foo_volume_1.id}"
  host_name = "${openstack_compute_instance_v2.foo_1.name}"
}
```

When I try to `TF_LOG=TRACE terraform apply -target=openstack_compute_instance_v2.foo_1` I get the following relevant output:

```
[TRACE] root: eval: *terraform.EvalWriteState
[TRACE] root: eval: *terraform.EvalApplyProvisioners
[TRACE] root: eval: *terraform.EvalIf
[TRACE] root: eval: *terraform.EvalWriteState
[TRACE] root: eval: *terraform.EvalWriteDiff
[TRACE] root: eval: *terraform.EvalApplyPost
[ERROR] root: eval: *terraform.EvalApplyPost, err: 1 error(s) occurred:

* openstack_compute_instance_v2.foo_1: Error creating OpenStack server: Invalid request due to incorrect syntax or missing required parameters.
[ERROR] root: eval: *terraform.EvalSequence, err: 1 error(s) occurred:

* openstack_compute_instance_v2.foo_1: Error creating OpenStack server: Invalid request due to incorrect syntax or missing required parameters.
[TRACE] [walkApply] Exiting eval tree: openstack_compute_instance_v2.foo_1
[TRACE] dag/walk: upstream errored, not walking "openstack_blockstorage_volume_attach_v2.foo_volume_1_attachment"
[TRACE] dag/walk: upstream errored, not walking "provider.openstack (close)"
[TRACE] dag/walk: upstream errored, not walking "meta.count-boundary (count boundary fixup)"
[TRACE] dag/walk: upstream errored, not walking "root"
[…]
[DEBUG] plugin: waiting for all plugin processes to complete...
Error: Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* openstack_compute_instance_v2.foo_1: 1 error(s) occurred:

* openstack_compute_instance_v2.foo_1: Error creating OpenStack server: Invalid request due to incorrect syntax or missing required parameters.
```

Since another instance was created successfully with a virtually identical `openstack_compute_instance_v2` declaration I suspect the problem is actually with the really badly documented `host_name`. Is it supposed to point to the name of an instance as in this case? If not, what is it supposed to point to?

Comment: The error is happening when creating the instance itself, not the volume or the volume attachment so it's most likely that you've made a mistake in the configuration there but it's impossible to tell with your truncated example.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR As mentioned there is another instance in the same configuration which was created successfully with virtually identical configuration, hence the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The error message turned out to be a red herring - I've updated the question with the relevant info. The issue is that when specifying a target instance which depends on a key pair the dependency is not resolved so the key pair is not created. Since the key pair is specific to the *account* rather than the tenant, terraform therefore tries to create an instance referring to a non-existing key pair.

Interestingly, this command would have worked for a person who had already applied the rest of the schema, because their key pair would already be created.